# Appending a icon based on the project count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a row which displays projects, now i `need to add an icon to the end` if the number of items exceed `6`. How can write a condition here to check if the project count is greater than 6 then instead of adding the projects i append a icon.

```
<div class="row">
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">          
     <%= link_to project.name, project_url(project.project_id),
              class: ('active' if current_page?(project_path(project.project_id)) ) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: your question isn't clear to me. Count of `@project`? and if count greater that 6 then add an icon else do what ?

Comment: add an icon only if the count is greater than 6... else just show the 6 projects in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `each_with_index` and then have a conditional in the loop to detect when you're on the 6th loop (first loop begins with zero for the `index` value).

Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @projects.each_with_index do |project, index| %>
    <% if index > 5 >
      <!-- show icon -->
    <% else %>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">          
       <%= link_to project.name, project_url(project.project_id),
              class: ('active' if current_page?(project_path(project.project_id)) ) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: @Frank,you want to append the icon to the same row as the link and/or div?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. If not then feel free to ask for change.

```
<% if @projects.size > 6 %>
###put your icon here
<% else %>
<div class="row">
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">          
     <%= link_to project.name, project_url(project.project_id),
              class: ('active' if current_page?(project_path(project.project_id)) ) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'each_with_index' instead of each , like this

```
<%@images.each_with_index do |page, index| %>
    <% if index > 5 %>
      //here put your code to add icon
    <%else%>
         <%= link_to project.name, project_url(project.project_id),
          class: ('active' if current_page?(project_path(project.project_id))
    <%end%>
 <%end%>
```

I think it will help you